# Versioning endpoints in Swagger 2

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger

I'm new to Swagger and I would like to be able to easily create a new version of endpoint should the need arise.  My `swagger.yaml` file looks something like this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: API
  description: blah
  contact:
    name: Some guy
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /log:
    x-swagger-router-controller: log
    post:
      summary: Creates a log entry.
      description: Creates a log entry.
      tags:
        - Logs
      security:
        - user: []
        - session: []
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
        400:
          description: Error
        401:
          description: Unauthorized
```

I pretty consistently see Swagger tutorials use /v1 or /v2, etc as their basepath.  This kinda begs the question... how would one increment the version of an *individual* endpoint?  What I have done so far is make the basepath `/` and then prepend each of the endpoint paths with `v1` (eg `v1/log`).  This solution doesn't scale very well though as I'll have a gigantic `swagger.yaml` file because I'll have every version of every endpoint in the file.  Not to mention, this also muddies the documentation because every endpoint is prepended with the version identifier.

Is there an easier or better way to do this with Swagger 2?

Comment: Did you handwritten the yaml? Perhaps use a generator to help you? In PHP I use generator to create these paths so I am fine with versioning. Not sure what are the options there with js.